# JPARepository @OneToOne, but to Abstract using State Pattern

Tags: java

I am using JPARepository, but I still don't know how to store a OneToOne relationship between two classes, Payment and Purchase.

Payment has 4 state, PaidPayment, UnpaidPayment, WaitingPayment, and SuccessPayment. All of them extends the Payment abstract.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "purchase")
public class Purchase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "purchase_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private long purchaseID;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "purchase", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Payment payment;

    // bunch of setters, getters, and constructor.
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Payment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "payment_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private long paymentID;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    private Purchase purchase;

    //bunch of getters, constructor, and setters.
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "payment")
public class UnpaidPayment extends Payment {

    Purchase purchase;

    public UnpaidPayment(Purchase purchase) {
        this.setStateName("Unpaid");
    }
}

// All states are like above, but different state name.
```

When I want to run, i got this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.bot.balgebunbot.database.model.Purchase.payment, referenced property unknown: com.bot.balgebunbot.database.model.payment.Payment.purchase
    at org.hibernate.cfg.OneToOneSecondPass.doSecondPass(OneToOneSecondPass.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1693) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1661) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1202) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1233) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Can @OneToOne relationship used in a pattern like this, or can i make this work? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```java
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "purchaseId")
private Purchase purchase;
```